# VBA Store Color Index in a Variable

Tags: excel, vba, colors

My program is supposed to check the colour index of a cell and then based on its colour, it increases a counter. For some reason I don't seem to be able to store the colour index to a variable though.

Here is the code:

```
Dim orange As Integer, green As Integer, blue As Integer, i As Integer, check As Long

For i = 0 To 79

    check = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Cells(i, 11).Interior.ColorIndex

    If check = 33 Then
        blue = blue + 1
    ElseIf check = 43 Then
        green = green + 1
    ElseIf check = 44 Then
        orange = orange + 1
    End If

Next I
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no row 0 start you counter at 1: `For i = 1 To 79`

Comment: You understand that 33, 43, and 44 are shades of blue, green and orange, not the 'base' colorindex numbers for blue, green and orange? See [ColorIndex table](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/excel-give-you-the-option-of-putting-in-three/9722c543-b106-456a-ad77-ff678e408b6d?msgId=2f1de6e1-636f-4b58-aa09-89bd7f10bbab).

Comment: @Jeeped I think you linked to the wrong page.  the link goes to the Range.TexttoColumns page

Comment: What do you expect `blue`, `green`, and `orange` to be? Where do you set those originally?  The first run through at `check = 33`, AFAIK `blue` will be set to `1`...then when `i = 2` and you hit `33` again, blue will be `2`. Is that what you expect to do?

Comment: *I don't seem to be able to store the colour index to a variable* <-- What makes you say this? Are there errors? Or do the results just not match what you expect? In either case, please clarify your problem statement for us.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks, I had another URL on the clipboard and my second copy didn't 'take'. Fixed now.

Comment: It was the issue of me trying to start at row 0. Thanks for your help all!

Comment: @Curtis see all answers you've got below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your i value starts at 0. Cell(0,11) is not a valid cell. Adjust your for-loop to start at 1.

```
Dim orange As Integer, green As Integer, blue As Integer, i As Integer, check As Long

For i = 1 To 79

    check = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Cells(i, 11).Interior.ColorIndex

    If check = 33 Then
        blue = blue + 1
    ElseIf check = 43 Then
        green = green + 1
    ElseIf check = 44 Then
        orange = orange + 1
    End If

Next I
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :P sorry for the dumb question. I feel really stupid...been a long day.

Comment: We've all been there! No worries! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Curtis - Sit back and accept the upvotes. This is one of the better questions I've seen today as it actually contains the code needed to address the inquiry.

Comment: I'm missing something - does OP want `blue`/`green`/`orange` to start at the value `1`?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to include all of the `ColorIndex`es provided by @Jeeped then you might want to change your coding a bit like so:

```
Dim orange As Long, green As Long, blue As Long, i As Long, check As Long

For i = 1 To 79

    check = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Cells(i, 11).Interior.ColorIndex

    Select Case check
    Case 33, 5, 8, 11, 23, 32, 25, 41, 55
        blue = blue + 1
    Case 43, 4, 10, 43, 50
        green = green + 1
    Case 44 To 46
        orange = orange + 1
    Case Else
        'colorNotFoundCounter = colorNotFoundCounter + 1
    End Select

Next i
```

Comment: Definitely use `Select Case` in this scenario :) Even though I thought of going another way

Answer (score 0):

You can store all type of colors in an array of colors `ColorArr`.

See code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub StoreIntColors_InArray()

Dim ColorArr() As Variant
Dim i As Long, check As Long

ReDim ColorArr(1 To 1000) ' resize color array to large number, per each type of color

For i = 1 To 79
    check = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Cells(i, 11).Interior.ColorIndex
    If check <> -4142 Then
        ColorArr(check) = ColorArr(check) + 1 ' <-- add 1 to the count of the specific color's array
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Normally I up-vote most of your answers. But in this case your solution is somewhat suboptimal (in my personal opinion). In the end you'll have a huge list to scan for and aggregate. Yet, if you were to change it to a dictionary-based solution with something like `If check <> -4142 Then : colorDictionary.Item(i) = colorDictionary.Item(i) + 1` then (at least) we'd have only as many keys in the dictionary as ColorIndexes actually used on the sheet. ;)

Comment: @Ralph  didn't think of the dictionary, that's a good idea, you should implement it. My wife told me to stay away from the PC and SO for the night :(